# PDFs stop generating from excel without explaination

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

My Excel 2007 macro generates 20 reports by replacing one cell with a look up value from a list, allowing a worksheet to update, and then exporting that worksheet to a PDF. After 8-10 are done the programme crashes, despite almost half having worked fine. The error message reads:

> Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure call or argument [Options: End or Debug or Help]

The PDF generating code is as follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printing").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:=fileName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

What could be the cause? Is RAM possible running out, and if so how can I reset it or clear it and keep the report generation going all the way to the end?

Comment: ...and your error stop procedure just on the `.ExportAsFixedFormat` line or where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the lenght of the file name. I shortened my filenames and magically everything works. Thank-you to anyone who gave up time to think about the problem.